# 'Generator' is not a member type of 'Self.SubSequence'

Tags: ios, swift, collections, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to convert the below Swift 2 extension method to Swift 3.

```
extension CollectionType {

    func chunk(withDistance distance: Index.Distance) -> [[SubSequence.Generator.Element]] {
        var index = startIndex
        let generator: AnyGenerator<Array<SubSequence.Generator.Element>> = anyGenerator {
            defer { index = index.advancedBy(distance, limit: self.endIndex) }
            return index != self.endIndex ? Array(self[index ..< index.advancedBy(distance, limit: self.endIndex)]) : nil
        }
        return Array(generator)
    }

}
```

The Xcode conversion tool left me with this.

```
extension Collection {

    func chunk(withDistance distance: Int) -> [[SubSequence.Iterator.Element]] {
        var index = startIndex
        let generator: AnyGenerator<Array<SubSequence.Generator.Element>> = anyGenerator {
            defer { index = index.advancedBy(distance, limit: self.endIndex) }
            return index != self.endIndex ? Array(self[index ..< index.advancedBy(distance, limit: self.endIndex)]) : nil
        }
        return Array(generator)
    }

}
```

Now I'm getting the above error at line, `let generator: AnyGenerator<Array<SubSequence.Generator.Element>> = anyGenerator {`. I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

- `Generator` has been renamed to `Iterator` in Swift 3, and consequently
  `AnyGenerator` to `AnyIterator`.
- `IndexDistance` is the associated type of `Collection` which 
  represents the number of steps between indices.
- In Swift 3, "Collections move their index", see
  [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution.

Putting it all together, your method could look in Swift 3 like this:

```
extension Collection {

    func chunk(withDistance distance: IndexDistance) -> [[SubSequence.Iterator.Element]] {
        var pos = startIndex
        let iterator: AnyIterator<Array<SubSequence.Iterator.Element>> = AnyIterator {
            // Already at the end?
            if pos == self.endIndex { return nil }

            // Compute `pos + distance`, but not beyond `self.endIndex`:
            let endPos = self.index(pos, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex

            // Return chunk and advance `pos`:
            defer { pos = endPos }
            return Array(self[pos..<endPos])
        }
        return Array(iterator)
    }
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let c = a.chunk(withDistance: 2)
print(c) // [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

I have renamed the local `index` variable to `pos`, to avoid
confusion with the

```
public func index(_ i: Self.Index, offsetBy n: Self.IndexDistance, limitedBy limit: Self.Index) -> Self.Index?
```

method of `Collection` which is used to advance the index.

Of course you could achieve the same result with a `while` loop
instead of an `Iterator`:

```
extension Collection {

    func chunk(withDistance distance: IndexDistance) -> [[SubSequence.Iterator.Element]] {
        var result: [[SubSequence.Iterator.Element]] = []
        var pos = startIndex
        while pos != endIndex {
            let endPos = self.index(pos, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            result.append(Array(self[pos..<endPos]))
            pos = endPos
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your second approach is much cleaner and easier to understand.